# vim regex & highlight syntax: find a match and ignore sub-match in it

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to write a syntax highlighter in VIM. How do you highlight a match within another match?

To find each match, I created two `syn match` lines, which work where the matches are separate.

```
syn match celString "^xpath=.\{-};"      -> matches "xpath=.........;"
syn match celComment "\${.\{-}}"         -> matches "${LIB_METADATA};"
```

---

[image: highlight syntax results - first line has separated matches, while second line has overlapping matches]

- The first line is pink for the xpath string and blue for the `${..}` string.
- The second line is pink for the xpath string, but the `${..}` contained inside that string is ignored.

I've tried to change the order of the `syn match` lines, but that doesn't have any effect.

I'd appreciate your ideas.

Comment: my guess is using groups? http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html#44.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Vim only applies the syntax groups to text that hasn't yet been assigned a syntax. To specify that one group can contain other groups, use the `contains=...` attribute:

```
:syn match celString "^xpath=.\{-};" contains=celComment
```

The order of definition shouldn't matter here. See `:help :syn-contains` for more information.